# How to auto update the electron application using the electron-updater?

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, electron-builder

I have an angular app which has been converted into a desktop app using the electron-builder. Now, I am trying to implement the auto-updates features into it. I don't want electron-builder to publish the changes to the github repository. (Note: The whole app is on a private github repo.) I want to manually upload the necessary .dmg, .zip, .yml files to the release tag and I want that to be picked up by the auto updater. How can I achieve this?

Currently, I have the source .zip and .tar.gz as part of my release tag. And whenever I try to invoke the `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()` when the app is ready, I get the following error saying:

```
Error: ENOENT, dev-app-update.yml not found in /Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar
at notFoundError (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:108:19)
    at fs.readFile (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:536:16)
    at go$readFile (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:85:14)
    at readFile (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:82:12)
    at readFile (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/universalify/index.js:5:67)
From previous event:
    at /Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:460:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at MacUpdater.loadUpdateConfig (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:456:33)
    at Lazy.AppUpdater.configOnDisk (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:142:43)
    at Lazy.get value [as value] (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/lazy-val/src/main.ts:18:23)
    at /Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:340:46
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
From previous event:
    at MacUpdater.getUpdateInfoAndProvider (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:336:43)
    at /Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:363:31
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
From previous event:
    at MacUpdater.doCheckForUpdates (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:360:34)
    at MacUpdater.checkForUpdates (/Users/userX/project-web/build/node_modules/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts:220:35)
    at Timeout.check [as _onTimeout] (/Users/userX/project-web/desktop/src/updater.ts:15:17)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
```

Here's my code:

updater.ts

```
import { autoUpdater } from 'electron-updater';
import { dialog, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';

const log = require('electron-log');
let downloadProgress: number;
log.transports.file.level = "debug";
autoUpdater.logger = log;

autoUpdater.autoDownload = false;

export function check() {
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
    dialog.showMessageBox({
        type: 'info',
        title: 'Update Available',
        message: 'A new version of app is available. Do you want to update now?',
        buttons: ['Update', 'No']
    }, (index) => {
        if (index) {
            return;
        } else {
            autoUpdater.downloadUpdate();

            let proWin = new BrowserWindow({
                width: 350,
                height: 35,
                useContentSize: true,
                autoHideMenuBar: true,
                maximizable: false,
                fullscreen: false,
                fullscreenable: false,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Downloading Update'
            });
            proWin.loadURL(`file://$(__dirname)/progress`);

            proWin.on('closed', () => {
                proWin = null;
            });

            ipcMain.on('download-progress-request', (e) => {
                e.returnValue = downloadProgress;
            });

            autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (d) => {
                downloadProgress = d.percent;
                autoUpdater.logger.info(downloadProgress);
            });

            autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
                if (progressWindow) progressWindow.close();

                dialog.showMessageBox({
                    type: 'info',
                    title: 'Update Ready',
                    message: 'A new version of app is ready. Quit and Install now?',
                    buttons: ['Yes', 'Later']
                }, (index) => {
                    if (!index) {
                        autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

}
The `check()` method in the updater.ts is invoked from the main.ts when the app is ready as follows:

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
   mainWinProcess() // handles all the browser window ops.
   createTray();
   setTimeout(updater.check, 2000); 
});
```

package.json as follows:

```
{
    "name": "project-web",
    "productName": "Project Web X",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "applecool",
    "description": "A func app",
    "main": "./main.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "electron-log": "2.2.17",
        "electron-updater": "4.0.4",
        "path": "0.12.7",
        "url": "0.11.0",
        "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
        "decompress-zip": "0.3.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "mac": "NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile ./ops/gulpfile.js mac",
        "mac-dev": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --gulpfile ./ops/gulpfile.js mac-dev",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/electron index.js --debug --enable-logging",
        "start-mac-setup-dev": "build --mac --config electron-builder-dev.yml",
        "start-mac-setup": "build --mac"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^10.12.9",
        "electron": "3.0.10",
        "electron-builder": "20.36.2",
        "electron-is-dev": "1.0.1",
        "electron-reload": "1.3.0",
        "gulp": "4.0.0",
        "icon-gen": "2.0.0",
        "jimp": "0.5.6",
        "os": "0.1.1",
        "zip-folder": "1.0.0",
        "devtron": "1.4.0"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.projectweb.x"
    }
}
```

Could anyone please point me in a right direction. I am trying to do this in the dev environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test, just start a local server then put your files (dmg, zip, yml, json) there (assuming that's on localhost:3000). Then, call API `.setFeedURL` ([document here](https://www.electron.build/auto-update#module_electron-updater.AppUpdater+setFeedURL)).

For example: `autoUpdater.setFeedURL("http://localhost:3000/latest-mac.json")` and call `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()`.

Note from  electron-builder document:

> Note that in order to develop/test UI/UX of updating without packaging
>   the application you need to have a file named dev-app-update.yml in
>   the root of your project, which matches your publish setting from
>   electron-builder config (but in yaml format). But it is not
>   recommended, better to test auto-update for installed application
>   (especially on Windows). Minio is recommended as a local server for
>   testing updates.

Comment: Thank you :) Will try to do that and get back.

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you again :)

Comment: @ShellZero No problem :)